# How to pass query string params or POST data to a redirected site when using Azure AD for login in between?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

If I am redirecting from one site to another with some query string params or Form POST data. But on redirection, I need the user to login through Azure AD authentication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication). 
How to enable the query string params and the POST data to be passed to the target site after successfully logging through Azure AD. 
(Does redirection after Azure AD authentication drops the query string params and the Form Post data?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "state" value in the login url to store these kinds of properties. Here is an example of the login url:

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&state=12345
```

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code):

> **state**
>
> A value included in the request that will also be returned in the token response. It can be a string of any content that you wish. A randomly generated unique value is typically used for preventing cross-site request forgery attacks. The state is also used to encode information about the user's state in the app before the authentication request occurred, such as the page or view they were on.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Does Azure AD wipe out form post data on successful redirection ?

Comment: I have two websites, one internal and the other hosted as Azure Website ( both leverages AAD for SSO)
Internal website redirects to Azure Website with Form Post Data. As Azure Website is AAD Authenticated, it redirects to login.microsoftonline.com, gets the token and comes back to Azure Website silently.
In the process of Auth, my form post data which was initially submitted is lost.
Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I am not 100% sure here, but my guess is that if it is not stored in the state variable, any data will get lost upon redirection to and from the login endpoint.